# Multiplying two double value gives negative number in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to multiply two large numbers for example,

```
 double x = 318191400000;
 double result =x*x;
```

But i am getting negative value for this when building in flutter .

Please help me on this.

[image: ref]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyxJ4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSs9P.png)

Comment: I have tried it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dart) and i'm not getting negative number here is the output `1.0124576703396e+23`

Comment: Hi @NileshRathod .. i have attached ref image. please check it

Comment: I see your screenshot, but I'm not able to reproduce this using either DartPad or local dart interpreter...

Comment: Could you please let me know your flutter version @magicleon94

Comment: I'm on the latest stable. I haven't tried with Flutter but with the stand alone dart interpreter on my machine, which is now on Dart 2.7

Comment: Please carefully check the values that your multiplying because I am getting same result as @NileshRathod.

Comment: Please provide an example that REALLY reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found solution and sharing here for anyone having these kind of issues,

```
xValues[index].toDouble() * yValues[index].toDouble()
```

This gives the expected result which is `1.0124576703396e+23`

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually multiplying two `double`s here, but two `int`s which is overflowing the 64-bit integer resulting in a negative number.

With doubles:

```dart
void main() {
  double x = 318191400000;
  print(x*x); // Result: 1.0124576703396e+23
}
```

With ints:

```dart
void main() {
  int x = 318191400000;
  print(x*x); // Result: -8411186631728820224
}
```

If you ever print a double to the console, you'll *always* see it displayed in either scientific notation (for extremely large or small values) or with a decimal point with at least one trailing digit.

Comment: you somehow got the point. Thanks for that. i have already found solution for my scenario and will explain below +1 for your comment